# Regex - match the better part of a word in a search string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Javascript and currently looking for a way to match as many of my pattern's letters as possible, maintaining the original order..

For example a search pattern `queued` should return the march `Queue`/`queue` against the any of the following search strings:

- `queueTable`
- `scheduledQueueTable`
- `qScheduledQueueTable`

As of now I've reached as far as this:

```
var myregex = new RegExp("([queued])", "i");
var result = myregex.exec('queueTable');
```

but it doesn't seem to work correctly as it highlights the single characters `q`,`u`,`e`,`u`,`e` and `e` at the end of the word `Table`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `q(u(e(u(ed?)?)?)?)?` do what you want?

Comment: @Rawing In fact not. `queued` is supposed to be an unknown variable and I need to be able to match the better part of it. So if the word is `foobar` and the search string is `foobaredTable` I am gonna need a match in `foobar`.

Comment: If the word you're trying to match is dynamic, obviously you'll have to dynamically create a pattern from it. There's no way around that.

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing - are you trying to find the text 'queued' in the text 'queueTable' - if so this will never be possible - did you mean 'queuedTable'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate the regex with [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) part where regex pattern can be generate using [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) method.

```js
var myregex = new RegExp("queued"
  .split('')
  .reduceRight(function(str, s) {
    return '(?:' + s + str + ')?';
  }, ''), "i");
var result = myregex.exec('queueTable');

console.log(result)
```

The method generates regex : [`/(?:q(?:u(?:e(?:u(?:e(?:d?)?)?)?)?)?)?/`](https://regex101.com/r/uRC0YX/1)

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to get the first longest match then use `g` modifier in regex and find out the largest using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
var myregex = new RegExp(
  "queued".split('')
  .reduceRight(function(str, s) {
    return '(?:' + s + str + ')?';
  }, ''), "ig");

var result = 'qscheduledQueueTable'
  .match(myregex)
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
  });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's great but won't work if the search string is something like "scheduledQueueTable"...

Comment: @kstratis : what is the expected o/p ?

Comment: I'd like to match as many letters as possible in this order located anywhere in the string. Thus for the search string `scheduledQueueTable` the match should be `Queue`.

Comment: Any help with that?

Comment: @kstratis :  do you need to start from anywhere ? for eg : do you want to match `edque`

Comment: No. There is no need for that. The order should be kept but needs to match as many characters as possible. For example `queued` should return `Queue` for `qscheduledQueueTable`, `scheduledQueueTable`,  and `queueTable`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136619/discussion-between-kstratis-and-pranav-c-balan).

Answer (score 3):

I think the logic would have to be something like:

> Match as many of these letters as possible, in this order.

The only real answer that comes to mind is to get the match to continue if possible, but allow it to bail out. In this case...

```
myregex = /q(?:u(?:e(?:u(?:e(?:d|)|)|)|)|)/;
```

You can generate this, of course:

```
function matchAsMuchAsPossible(word) { // name me something sensible please!
    return new RegExp(
        word.split("").join("(?:")
        + (new Array(word.length).join("|)"))
    );
}
```

Comment: It works but not in the exact way I want it to. See my comment above on @Pranav's answer. You got the logic correct. However I want it to search anywhere within the search string. Thus if the search string is `scheduledQueueTable`, `Queue` should be highlighted for pattern `queued`.

Comment: Just add the `i` modifier to the regex?

Comment: Well it does work. However there is an edge case it won't catch. If I change the search string to `qscheduledQueueTable` it will fail catching only the first `q` character insted of `Queue`. Please have a look at this example: https://regex101.com/r/NFBS7l/1

Comment: Try adding the `g` modifier, then scan the results for the longest match.

Comment: That did the trick but @Pranav also handed an implementation, I accepted his answer. However for the record, you were the first to figure out my true goal...

Answer (score 1):

You are using square brackets - which mean that it will match a single instance of any character listed inside.

There are a few ways of interpreting your intentions:

You want to match the word queue with an optional 'd' at the end:

```
var myregex = new RegExp("queued?", "i");
var result = myregex.exec('queueTable');
```

Note this can be shorter try this:
    `'queueTable'.match(/queued?/i);`

I also removed the brackets as these were not adding anything here.

This link provides some good examples that may help you further: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Answer (score 1):

When you use [] in a regular expression, it means you want to match any of the characters inside the brackets.

Example: if I use `[abc]` it means "match a single character, and this character can be 'a', 'b' or 'c'"

So in your code `[queued]` means "match a single character, and this character can be 'q', 'u', 'e' or 'd'" - note that 'u' and 'e' appear twice so they are redundant in this case. That's why this expression matches just one single character.

If you want to match the whole string "queued", just remove the brackets. But in this case it won't match, because queueTable doesn't have 'd'. If you want 'd' to be optional, you can use `queued?` as already explained in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following :

```js
var myregex = /queued?\B/g;
var result = myregex.exec('queueTable');
console.log(result);
```